# Why is not operator giving different result but using = giving correct answer

Tags: java, operators

```
 static int count = 0;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    count = 0;
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int arr[][] = new int[n][n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        arr[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
      }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++) {
      row(arr, n, i);
      column(arr, n, i);
    }
    System.out.println(count);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " ");
      }
    }
  }

  static void row(int arr[][], int n, int row) {
    int x, y, min, yHold = 0;

    for (x = 0; x < n; x++) {
      boolean yes = false;
      min = arr[row][x];

      for (y = row; y < n; y++) {
        if (arr[y][x] < min) {
          min = arr[y][x];
          yHold = y;
          yes = true;
        }
      }
      if (yes) {
        int temp = arr[row][x];
        arr[row][x] = min;
        arr[yHold][x] = temp;
        count++;
      }
    }
```

If I replace `yes=true` with `yes=!yes`, the output becomes different. Please help, can't seem to figure it out.
The part of the problem the function row is taking are of is:

> If we are at ith row, then we have to work with each column at a time
>   from 0 to n−1 of this row. For any jth column, swap A[i][j] with the
>   minimum of all the elements which are present in a column with index j
>   and rows from indices i to n−1.

Comment: What happens if `yes = !yes` is executed twice?

Comment: Yes, I understand now. Apparently my test case was so, that the required number was occurring in odd position most of the time, that's why I was stuck at this. Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say `yes = true`, it is always going to be true. But when you say, `yes = !yes` it will flip back and forth between true and false.

```
boolean yes = true;
for (int i = i < 10; i++) {
 System.out.println(yes);   
 yes =! yes;
}
```

prints

```
true
false
true
false
true
false
true
false
true
false
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the statement can be executed multiple times. In the case of `yes = true`, the result will always be that `yes` becomes `true`. But with `yes = !yes`, the result is that `yes` will flip flop between `true` and `false`.